# Is there a way to make Linq to Entities map unrecognized methods/functions to MySql functions?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, linq-to-entities

Is there a way to make Linq to Entities map unrecognized methods/functions to MySql functions?

I want to add support to some functions like Convert.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [you can do this in EF 4 using `EdmFunctionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456847%28VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: so currently in Net 3.5 is impossible?

Comment: Harder, anyway. You'd have to write a `DefiningQuery` or view.